# Error while trying to connect Azure usng power shell 6.0.0-rc

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to connect to my Azure account using power shell on my machine and getting following error. I have installed Powershell 6.0.0-rc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welp, just use silent authentication. .NET core probably doesnt have that assembly ported so it cannot present you the login popup window. If you use silent auth (any method) it might work. I'm saying "might" because there can be other difficulties.

Also, you should use the AzureRm.Netcore.preview module (at least thats what I would expect) with the Powershell 6.0